# How i can call winform from wpf window

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Here is the code in wpf window that is calling two winform :

```
(new TWSMIS.Customer.New_CustomerF()).Show();
(new TWSMIS.Voucher.Create_Dv_VouchersF()).Show();
```

Here project name is "TWSMIS" folder names are "Customer" and "Voucher" respectively .In this code only first line is giving error of :`"   The type or namespace name 'New_CustomerF' does not exist in the namespace 'TWSMIS.Customer' (are you missing an assembly reference?)   C:\Users\SKJ\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\TWSMIS\TWSMIS\HomePage.xaml.cs"` While second line is executing correctly .Can some body tell me how to correct this error?

Comment: is System.Windows.Forms reference in your project?

Comment: yes .System.Windows.Forms reference is present

Comment: I guess New_CustomerF is private or internal. You need to make that public.

Comment: Can you add code which defines New_CustomerF class?

Comment: Ok ...i found mistake ...namespace TWSMIS.Customer
{
    public partial class Create_Dv_VouchersF : Form
    {..........class name was misplaced .....Thanks for assistance ...

Comment: Please consider those that will need to maintain your code in the future when making decisions like this... they will most certainly curse your name if you do this in any sort of production application